# How to calculate gradient for this multivariable function

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule

I'm trying to calculate the gradient of the following multi-variable function:

$$ f(m,b) =  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n {(y_i-(mx_i + b))^2}$$

I want to use Chain rule as 
$${(y_i-(mx_i + b))^2}$$
is a composite function. I'd like to calculate $$\frac{df}{dm}$$ and $$\frac{df}{db}$$

Can somebody show me how to derive this? Thank you.

Comment: This is a fairly standard calculation, needed for fitting a line to data points with a least-squares error objective.  Since the derivatives are *partial* we prefer the notations $\partial f/\partial m$ and $\partial f/\partial b$.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: I can't see a way by which I can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the i-th component of the sum:

$$f_i(m,b)=\frac{1}{n}{(y_i-(mx_i + b))^2}$$

thus:

$$\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial m}=\frac{2}{n}{(y_i-(mx_i + b))}(-x_i)$$

$$\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial b}=\frac{2}{n}{(y_i-(mx_i + b))}(-1)$$

and then adding up.

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial m}= \frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n {-x_i(y_i-(mx_i + b))}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}= \frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n {-(y_i-(mx_i + b))}$$

**NOTE**

The functions to derive are in the form:

$$f(t)=[g(t)]^2\implies f'(t)=2g(t)g'(t)$$

Comment: @AlexanderKheirallah You are welcome, if you are ok you can upvote and accept the aswer, bye! https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer